# How can I reconnect to my friend whom I previously blocked?

Tags: facebook, friends

I have block the one of my friend from my facebook profile, but now we want to reconnect again.... a strange truth of life.

Perhaps, Facebook doesn't want that and me & my friend both are not able to see each other profile/post ... anything and everything.. which is making an impossible task for us to send a friend request.

In simple words,

How can I reconnect to my friend whom I previously blocked?

Comment: Don't do that :D

Comment: @Manoochehr Like I said, this is a strange truth and to err is human.. after a while u realize the friend you need the most is got igonred by your mistake. I want to correct that :)

Comment: Well, I hope everything will be ok.

Comment: Just as an alternative method of doing this going forward: I have a "time out" group that, in my default post security settings, is blocked from seeing any content I post. When someone I know needs to be timed out, I simply place them in this group. Then, when I want them to see stuff I've posted again, I remove them from this group. It's not a true block, but it allows some cool-down time so I retain the friendship and don't burn out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'll go to the [Privacy Settings](http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy), on the bottom you will see a `Block Lists` section, where you can `Edit your lists` of blocked people and apps. From there I guess you'll see your friend's name somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on `Account -> Edit Friends`, you'll find a list of all your friends. On the left sidebar is a list of all your friend groups including Limited Profile. You can move friends around from this page.

A blocked friend is one that has very tight bottle-neck restrictions. moving him/her to a group with little/no restrictions should allow you reconnect freely.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings at the extreme right bottom of your profile Picture, select time line settings, click Blocking then go to manage Blocking and unblock the person from the list then you will be free to re-send a friends request.